# CNTK Binary Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, cntk

We are just getting start on a project to utilize CNTK to create a binary classifier.

Our data set looks like this:

```
|attribs 1436000 24246.3124164245 |isMatch 1
|attribs 535000 21685.9351529239 |isMatch 1
|attribs 729000 8988.24232231086 |isMatch 1
|attribs 436000 4787.7521169184 |isMatch 1
|attribs 110000 38236394.456649 |isMatch 0
|attribs 808000 39512500.9870238 |isMatch 0
|attribs 108000 28432968.9161523 |isMatch 0
|attribs 816000 39512231.5629576 |isMatch 0
```

We are trying to determine whether or not a school bus stop matches a planned route. The first value is the delta time in ms between the planned stop and the actual stop and the second value is the delta distance between the planned location and the actual location (millimeters).

The problem I am having is (probably a fundamental misunderstanding of how to use CNTK) that no matter how I tweak the data, or the hidden nodes, or the batch size, or any of the other knobs, I continue to get almost identical results. I can eval the most ludicrous of inputs and I keep getting 1.00 out.

How should I modify either the data or the model to get more accurate results?

The full code is here:

```
import numpy as np
import cntk as C
from cntk import Trainer  # to train the NN
from cntk.learners import sgd, learning_rate_schedule, \
    UnitType
from cntk.ops import *  # input_variable() def
from cntk.logging import ProgressPrinter
from cntk.initializer import glorot_uniform
from cntk.layers import default_options, Dense
from cntk.io import CTFDeserializer, MinibatchSource, \
    StreamDef, StreamDefs, INFINITELY_REPEAT


def my_print(arr, dec):
    # print an array of float/double with dec decimals
    fmt = "%." + str(dec) + "f"  # like %.4f
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        print(fmt % arr[i] + '  ', end='')
    print("\n")


def create_reader(path, is_training, input_dim, output_dim):
    return MinibatchSource(CTFDeserializer(path, StreamDefs(
        features=StreamDef(field='attribs', shape=input_dim,
                           is_sparse=False),
        labels=StreamDef(field='isMatch', shape=output_dim,
                         is_sparse=False)
    )), randomize=is_training,
                           max_sweeps=INFINITELY_REPEAT if is_training else 1)


def save_weights(fn, ihWeights, hBiases,
                 hoWeights, oBiases):
    f = open(fn, 'w')
    for vals in ihWeights:
        for v in vals:
            f.write("%s\n" % v)
    for v in hBiases:
        f.write("%s\n" % v)
    for vals in hoWeights:
        for v in vals:
            f.write("%s\n" % v)
    for v in oBiases:
        f.write("%s\n" % v)
    f.close()


def do_demo():
    # create NN, train, test, predict
    input_dim = 2
    hidden_dim = 30
    output_dim = 1
    train_file = "trainData_cntk.txt"
    test_file = "testData_cntk.txt"
    input_Var = C.ops.input_variable(input_dim, np.float32)
    label_Var = C.ops.input_variable(output_dim, np.float32)
    print("Creating a 2-21 tanh softmax NN for Stop data ")
    with default_options(init=glorot_uniform()):
        hLayer = Dense(hidden_dim, activation=C.ops.tanh,
                       name='hidLayer')(input_Var)
        oLayer = Dense(output_dim, activation=C.ops.softmax,
                       name='outLayer')(hLayer)
    nnet = oLayer
    # ----------------------------------
    print("Creating a cross entropy mini-batch Trainer \n")
    ce = C.cross_entropy_with_softmax(nnet, label_Var)
    pe = C.classification_error(nnet, label_Var)
    fixed_lr = 0.05
    lr_per_batch = learning_rate_schedule(fixed_lr,
                                          UnitType.minibatch)
    learner = C.sgd(nnet.parameters, lr_per_batch)

    trainer = C.Trainer(nnet, (ce, pe), [learner])
    max_iter = 5000  # 5000 maximum training iterations
    batch_size = 100  # mini-batch size  5
    progress_freq = 1000  # print error every n minibatches
    reader_train = create_reader(train_file, True, input_dim,
                                 output_dim)
    my_input_map = {
        input_Var: reader_train.streams.features,
        label_Var: reader_train.streams.labels
    }
    pp = ProgressPrinter(progress_freq)
    print("Starting training \n")
    for i in range(0, max_iter):
        currBatch = reader_train.next_minibatch(batch_size,
                                                input_map=my_input_map)
        trainer.train_minibatch(currBatch)
        pp.update_with_trainer(trainer)
    print("\nTraining complete")
    # ----------------------------------
    print("\nEvaluating test data \n")
    reader_test = create_reader(test_file, False, input_dim,
                                output_dim)
    numTestItems = 200
    allTest = reader_test.next_minibatch(numTestItems,
                                         input_map=my_input_map)
    test_error = trainer.test_minibatch(allTest)
    print("Classification error on the test items = %f"
          % test_error)
    # ----------------------------------
    # make a prediction for an unknown flower
    # first train versicolor = 7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,0,1,0
    unknown = np.array([[10000002000, 24275329.7232828]], dtype=np.float32)
    print("\nPredicting Stop Match for input features: ")
    my_print(unknown[0], 1)  # 1 decimal
    predicted = nnet.eval({input_Var: unknown})
    print("Prediction is: ")
    my_print(predicted[0], 3)  # 3 decimals
    # ---------------------------------
    print("\nTrained model input-to-hidden weights: \n")
    print(hLayer.hidLayer.W.value)
    print("\nTrained model hidden node biases: \n")
    print(hLayer.hidLayer.b.value)
    print("\nTrained model hidden-to-output weights: \n")
    print(oLayer.outLayer.W.value)
    print("\nTrained model output node biases: \n")
    print(oLayer.outLayer.b.value)
    save_weights("weights.txt", hLayer.hidLayer.W.value,
                 hLayer.hidLayer.b.value, oLayer.outLayer.W.value,
                 oLayer.outLayer.b.value)
    return 0  # success


def main():
    print("\nBegin Stop Match \n")
    np.random.seed(0)
    do_demo()  # all the work is done in do_demo()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
# end script
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that your output layer is using a `softmax()` activation function, but then you are using `cross_entropy_with_softmax()` as your loss function. As a consequence, at training time your result is being evaluated as a softmax on a softmax.

Use `activation=None` in your output layer and see how your training gets on.

In your prediction code, you will then obviously have to apply softmax to your evaluations, so something like `C.ops.softmax(nnet).eval({input_Var: unknown})`. Looking back at an example I did, I used `C.softmax`, but that just might be a namespace difference from when I wrote that example versus the version of CNTK your are using.

PS: if you are doing binary classification then you really don't need to use softmax as that's really intended for use in multiclass classification problems. It should still work in a binary case though.

PPS: During training it would be useful to print out the loss after each minibatch so you can see if gradient descent is converging. I think you'll find in your current model that it is not.

PPS: I just noticed your variable `output_dim` is set to 1. I don't know what behaviour you will get with softmax in this situation. Normally softmax would be applied to a one hot encoded output, so in the binary case you would have two outputs that would give the probability of the correct result being a zero or a one. Equally you need to obviously one hot encode your ground truth before training. Can't tell you for sure whether your approach does or doesn't work, but it looks fishy.

Comment: I really wish I fully understood what you said here. But as a total noob here I do not. Any chance you cpuld direct me to some reading to get up to speed?

Comment: I don't know of a faster route than completing http://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/welcome

Answer (score 1):

When you do `softmax` on a vector with a single element you are going to get 1 in the output no matter what you do. The right way is to have two outputs (also make the labels be "0 1" or "1 0") and don't use a softmax activation because `cross_entropy_with_softmax` has the softmax built-in.

Once you do this you will probably run into other issues, most notably that the inputs are huge. Neural nets like their inputs to be small and centered around 0. I would normalize each feature by subtracting its mean value on the training set and divide by its standard deviation.